# How to select file in os.path.join from only two folders names while excluding others using regex Python?

Tags: python, regex, glob

I would like to create a list of files that are located inside two subfolder (2013,2014) of a main one (SPOTVGT_MC10) containing many more.

My current code is the following:

```
sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_MNR,'SPOTVGT_MC10','*','*MIR.tif')))
```

I would like to replace the first * by something that would only consider the folders named 2013 and 2014, probably using a regular expression.

Do you know a way to achieve it?

Thanking you in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_MNR,'SPOTVGT_MC10','201[34]','*MIR.tif')))
```

As explained [in the fnmatch module docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html):

> [seq] matches any character in seq

Notice, also, that these are

> Unix shell-style wildcards, which are not the same as regular expressions

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer to your question once you feel your problem has been solved or upvote what looks like a good answer to you.